# Magento log is not writing in log folder

Tags: magento-1.9, log, debugging

Log files are not writing in the log folder but previously  they are writing in the folder. Any idea about this?.

Comment: Is there a solution yet?

Answer (score 6):

There are several possible options here:

1. Logs have been disabled under **System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled**
2. **Your server is full** and thus can't write to the logs anymore.
3. Maybe **there's nothing to log** (which is a good thing as that means there's no **error/warning** to log on your website)
4. Maybe **your `var/log` folder permissions have changed** and thus Magento cannot write to this folder anymore.

Comment: Is any possibility of hacking to prevent log writing?

Comment: @AkhilKurian well I don't see why someone would prevent log writing to hack your website. There's no reason behind that. I've added an extra reason

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)' in /var/www/html/bluemountainorganics/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129


I got this error in yesterday  on cron is any idea aboutthis ?

Comment: @AkhilKurian well it has nothing to do with the logs. It means Magento couldn't connect to MySQL, there's several reasons: maybe the Database server was down, the credentials have changed or you're out of space in your server

Comment: Permissions. Check if logging is not going to /tmp/magento/var/log ( off the top of my head, so could be incorrect path)

Comment: Yes ,logs are going to the  /tmp/magento/var/log folder , how to change back to the magento folder.

Comment: delete `/tmp/magento`, make `var/log` writable for the web server (using chown and chmod), then the fallback direcory in `/tmp` is not used anymore

Comment: If you add 4th param to be true then you are supposed to write logs even when logs are disabled. For example: Mage::log("something", null, special_file_name.log, true);

Answer (score 4):

In 1.9.4.1 (or after applying SUPEE-11086 patch) if you delete "**/var/log/system.log**" log file becomes "*not writeable*" (even if directory is writeable), so Magento skips writing log.

Solution:

- make sure "/var/log/" is writeable
- create empty "/var/log/system.log" there
- and/or wait when it will be fixed by Magento devs

Answer (score 2):

I've found that if SELinux is not set properly for Magento, nothing gets written to the Magento logs, but instead goes to the /tmp location. Try 'setenforce Permissive' to disable SELinux. If the logs begin to receive output, then SELinux was to blame. Unfortunately, I do not know how to allow the Magento user (on CentOS it's apache) to write to the log files. With SELinux, even setting permissions on that file to 777 doesn't help.

So, by disabling SELinux with 'setenforce Permissive', just remember that after a reboot, it will be enabled again.

Comment: This worked in my case, to keep it permanent edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` with `SELINUX=permissive`. Details [here](https://www.certdepot.net/selinux-set-enforcing-and-permissive-modes)

Answer (score 0):

@sv3n solution above worked for me.

Creating empty files in the var/log folder for system.log and exception.log allowed them to work again.

On v1.9.3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Check under /tmp/magento

i.e. /tmp/magento/var/log

When magento has a problem writing to var/logs|cache|sessions, sometimes it writes to /tmp/magento/var/* instead, which is the default location.

Even once the original issue is fixed it often keeps writing them to /tmp/magento/var/log.